if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then $f\in L^p$ for $1\leq p$
I am trying to prove that if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then $f\in L^p$ for $1\leq p$.
I have seen the same question posted here but I cannot understand the answer:
"Since $\hat{f}\in L^1$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous. So you can set
$$f = f_++f_- \qquad\qquad f_+(x) = f(x) 1_{|f(x)| \ge 1} \qquad\qquad f_-(x) = f(x) 1_{|f(x)| < 1}$$
and $f_+$ is compactly supported.
Finally since $f\in L^1$
$\|f\|_{L^p}^p \le \|f_-\|_{L^1}^p+\|f_+\|_{L^p}^p < \infty$"
I don't understand why since $\hat f\in L^1$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous and where does the inequality come from?
Edit: $\hat f$ being the Fourier transform of $f$

It is this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2455200 answer.

I think the power $p$ at $||f_-||_{L^1}^p$ should not be there (see answer).

@psl2Z Yes you're right I should have posted the link to the original answer. As for the $p$ I felt something was odd but I could not explain clearly what.

Let $\mathcal{F}: L^1 \to L^\infty$ be the Fourier transform. Then it is $\mathcal{F}(L^1) \subseteq C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of continuous functions $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ with $g(x) \to 0$ for $|x| \to \infty$. This is the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. The functions $g \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are uniformly continuous.
Write it out:
$$||f||^p_{L^p} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|^pdx = \int_{\{|f(x)|\geq 1\}}|f|^pdx + \int_{\{|f(x)|< 1\}}|f|^pdx $$
and it is $|y|^p \leq |y|$ for $|y| \leq 1$, so $\int_{\{|f(x)|< 1\}}|f|^pdx \leq \int_{\{|f(x)|< 1\}}|f|dx = ||f_-||_{L^1}$. Further $\int_{\{|f(x)|\geq 1\}}|f|^pdx = ||f_+||_{L^p}^p.$
Therefore $||f||_{L^p}^p \leq ||f_-||_{L^1} + ||f_+||_{L^p}^p < \infty$, since $f \in L^1$, so $f_- \in L^1$, and $\{|f| \geq 1\}$ is compact, since $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, so $||f_+||_{L^p}^p \leq \lambda(\{|f|\geq 1\}) ||f||_{L^\infty} < \infty$.

Very clear and concise, cheers!
